# How to get rid of junk code when knit to PDF

Tags: r, rstudio

I am knitting to pdf, but while it is outputting my graphs, it is also outputting the below. How do I stop R from outputting this?

```
##
## Attaching package: 'dplyr'
## The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
##
## filter, lag
## The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
##
## intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
## Registering fonts with R
Importing fonts may take a few minutes, depending on the number of fonts and the speed of the system.
Continue? [y/n]
## Exiting.
## Arial Black already registered with windowsFonts().
## Arial already registered with windowsFonts().
## Arial Narrow already registered with windowsFonts().
```

Code:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)
library(extrafont)
font_import()
loadfonts(device = 'win')

x <- seq(1,9,by = 1)

kable(x,format = 'latex', booktabs = T, caption = "A KnitR Kable")
```
````

Comment: added the code to question

Comment: According to the [**`extrafont` documentation**](https://github.com/wch/extrafont), you only need to run `font_import()` and then `loadfonts()` once (unless you install new fonts, which requires re-running the above commands) and the fonts will then be available to R in future sessions.

Comment: In addition to the other answers, another option is to use the `include=FALSE` option in the chunk where you load the packages. Within the first chunk you can also add the following command to globally surpress warnings and messages in all future chunks: `knitr::opts_chunk$set(warning=FALSE, message=FALSE)`. This can be globally reversed at a later time with the same command but with TRUE in place of FALSE, or reversed for any single chunk by setting that chunk's options to the desired values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's common to have a separate section where you load all of your packages and include the `message = FALSE, warning = FALSE` options. This silences the output and keeps the file from being filled with the sometimes copious amounts of warnings loading packages can cause:

````
```{r, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)
library(extrafont)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
font_import()
loadfonts(device = 'win')

x <- seq(1,9,by = 1)

kable(x,format = 'latex', booktabs = T, caption = "A KnitR Kable")
```
````

Just be sure no warnings or messages that are pertinent to the user are being silenced.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you need to do:

1. Make sure all code has been run ahead of time at least once to download everything (I'm sure this has already been done)
2. `font_import(prompt=F)` disables the prompt. This can also be wrapped in `suppressMessages()` if needed.

You should also feel free to use `suppressMessages()` anywhere else you may need it, but be sure you know what those messages are before you suppress them.

Also, from an even "higher level" of the architecture, I'm not sure if you even really need all these in your code block. Why not run them before or elsewhere?  Well, if there's a strong reason, then refer to the advice above. Otherwise it's easy to put noisy code in one block and not show its output, then put your `kable` line and other quite code in the block whose output you'll display.